# Jquery Datables how to make the 2 first rows fixed

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using: jquery.dataTables.js from: https://datatables.net

I am trying to make the 2 first rows fixed, I am using drag drop so all the rows now are drag-gable.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f7debwj2/14/

html:

```
  <br>
  <br>
  <table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Place</th>
         <th>Order</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dt = $('#example').dataTable();
  dt.fnDestroy();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/clmDuyndua?indent=2';
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: url,
    createdRow: function(row, data, dataIndex){
      $(row).attr('id', 'row-' + dataIndex);
    },
    rowReorder: {
       dataSrc: 'order',
    },
    columns: [
      {
         data: 'order'
      },{
         data: 'name'
      },{
         data: 'place'
    }]
  });
    table.rowReordering();  

});
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear too as you are thinking to disturb the nature of dataTable...

Comment: not clear? I am trying to make the first 2 rows fixed simple as that.

Comment: You got them non-drag-able by disallowing any event from mouse or touch...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using CSS-

Assuming that dataTable gives fixed **id** to rows-

```
row#row-0,row#row-2{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Just copy paste the above code in the fiddle you created.

If sorting and other sort of things are available then it will change its position. Another approach is to manipulate the output and keeping the two rows in header section.